# Spliting a long row of records in the 'Section' into two or more rows

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, obiee

I have a very simple requirement. I have placed large number of attributes/columns in the 'Section' part of the table view due to which the report has became too wide and hence when exported to PDF it results in a very small font size. I just want to split the attributes in the Section into two or more rows. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider getting rid of some of those attributes and move them to dashboard prompts instead. Any attribute in the "section" part of a table view (or any other view) doesn't filter your data when retrieved from the physical sources.
At the moment when you run that analysis you have a query returning a huge data set and you fake it by displaying only a little piece on screen.

You could avoid the issue of the width by using dashboard prompts which will physically filter your query instead. 
And a dashboard prompt can be split into multiple rows.
All in all multiple small, filtered queries retrieving small sets of data don't perform worse than a single huge query and hiding data on screen.

If you really want to split that row of selections into 2 rows you will need to add some custom CSS/js for the job, but it isn't going to change the PDF export: the PDF export process will not be able to understand your custom CSS/js and therefore still generating the exact same PDF.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I'm not allowed to change the fields in the Dashboard prompt, so that's not an option for me. Could you please elaborate as what exactly would the CSS/js code be?

Comment: Open the analysis not in edit-mode but either in preview or as it is in your page. Open the developer extension of your browser and explore the code representing the sections and find a unique pattern identifying the place where you want to break the line. Then either play with CSS to split it into 2 rows.

Keep in mind OBIEE pages are generated, therefore your pattern must be as precise as possible to identify the place to be applied to, and not too generic or it could change other pieces of the page.

Answer (score 0):

A common table expression (CTE) will allow you to split a single record into multiple records. You are going to have to figure out the basis for splitting.

```
WITH
    starter AS
        (SELECT 'This is my really long text. It is really long. Just how long remains to be seen.'    txt
           FROM DUAL),
    splitit ( line, txt ) AS
        (SELECT SUBSTR( txt
                      , 1
                      , INSTR( txt, '.' ) )             AS line
              , SUBSTR( txt, INSTR( txt, '.' ) + 1 )    AS txt
           FROM starter
         UNION ALL
         SELECT SUBSTR( txt
                      , 1
                      , INSTR( txt, '.' ) )             AS line
              , SUBSTR( txt, INSTR( txt, '.' ) + 1 )    AS txt
           FROM splitit
          WHERE txt IS NOT NULL)
SELECT line
  FROM splitit;
```

This results in:

```
LINE
This is my really long text.
 It is really long.
 Just how long remains to be seen.
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the reply. Secondly, I wanted to this on OBIEE (what you showed in your answer is for like sql query), and thirdly, its not a long text here which I am trying to split. Its a long list of columns/attributes, all arranged in a single row in the 'Section' part of a table view in OBIEE. Hope I am clear enough this time :)